# How to recover code from .java?

Tags: eclipse, recovery

I was writing code last night and when I open the code this morning I find this... Is there any way to recover the code from last night?

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you still have it in your local history. Right click in your class -> team -> show local history.

Comment: No local history was found.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the .jar or .class file try this:

http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Maybe you've renamed the file accidentally ?

Comment: It seems like those files got wiped as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Eclipse, lets try with Eclipse's local history features. Try search for local history. Right click MelodynGen.java -> Compare With -> Local history. Eclipse should open History view and you can click on previous versions of your file. You can compare two versions by selecting two versions in history view, right click -> Compare with each other. When you have found the right version you want to recover, right click that version -> Get Contents. Eclipse asks if you really want to overwrite current file to that version. Other way is to open desired history version, select all, copy, open MelodyGen.java -> paste.

Comment: So if none of what you mentioned succeeds, I'm assuming I have to start from scratch again?

Comment: Propably yes. Of course there are tools to do things to the hard drive but that would most likely require more effort than just start from scracth. Did you try to search that history? Any luck?